# $.ajax won't access url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send some data via jquery and $.ajax to a php file. When the page loads, a list of names is retrieved from "bewohner_func.php". This works.

At the end of the list is a form, which is used to add a new Name onto the list. It uses $.ajax to send the data, also to "bewohner_func.php", using a switch to differntiate from displaying or adding the data-. Problem is, when I try to send the form, the script does not include the php file. I can safely say that it's not the php file's fault, as I reduced it to an alert.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{       
    $("#bew_new").submit(function() 
        {
            var frmData = $("#bew_new").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                    url: "bewohner_func.php",
                    data: frmData,
                    success: function(msg)
                        {
                            $('#bewohnerliste').fadeOut(400);
                            $.get("bewohner_func.php", {'bew_new': '0'}, function(data){
                                $("#bewohnerliste").html(data);
                            });
                            $('#bewohnerliste').fadeIn(400);
                        }
                });
            return false;

        });

});
```

This is the code for displaying, which does it's job fine:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $.get("bewohner_func.php", {'bew_new': '0'}, function(data){
        $("#bewohnerliste").html(data);
    });
});
```

The form:

```
        <form id="bew_new" class="bew_form" action="bewohner_func.php" method="get">
        <input name="anrede" size="6" value="Anrede" onFocus="if(this.value=='Anrede')this.value=''">
        <input name="name" value="Name" onFocus="if(this.value=='Name')this.value=''">
        <input name="wohnbereich" size="2" value="WB" onFocus="if(this.value=='WB')this.value=''">
        <input type="submit" value="Neu anlegen">
    </form>
```

Comment: I can only think of the fact that the form is being submitted anyway ..

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are running your `submit` handler code on page load before form is loaded. If so, submit handler won't be bound to form if it doesn't exist.

You can delegate the handler to an eleemnt, or the document itself, that will be permanent asset in page

TRY:

```
$("#bewohnerliste").on('submit',"#bew_new",function(){

     var frmData = $(this).serialize();
       $.ajax......
})
```

Comment: That broke the script. Now the form submits it's contents without jquery, so a regular POST-Refresh. Changing #bewohnerliste to #bew_new (they are seperate, #bewohnerliste is only for displaying the database) and removing the second #bew_new the script fires again, but netting in the same result: The php won't get accessed.

Comment: `second #bew_new` ? That implies duplicating ID in page which you can't do. Use browser console nework tab to inspect request closely. status, data sent, what is returnd ( if any) etc. Need more clues and that is best place to start

Comment: I've been a moron. The php query was wrong. Using the console i figured, that the request went through, but had no output. Fixed. Thank you.

Comment: yup...that's why console always first place to look....need to know which end is the problem